# Добавление репозитория Debian Testing

Tags: debian, repository, testng

Я хочу добавить репозиторий в свежеустановленный Debian Testing

Сначала он говорил что не знает команду add-apt-repository. Я установил следующее

> sudo apt-get install software-properties-common  software-properties-gtk gnupg dirmngr

и теперь он мне выдает это.

> me@  [~] $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq
>
> Notepadqq text editor
>
> More info:
>   https://launchpad.net/~notepadqq-team/+archive/ubuntu/notepadqq
>
> Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
>
> gpg: создан щит с ключами '/tmp/tmp64fpd42d/pubring.gpg'
>
> gpg: /tmp/tmp64fpd42d/trustdb.gpg: создана таблица доверия
>
> gpg: ключ 2E30EE6263DE9CD4: импортирован открытый ключ "Launchpad PPA
>   for Notepadqq Team"
>
> gpg: Всего обработано: 1
>
> gpg:                  импортировано: 1
>
> gpg: не найдено данных формата OpenPGP. Exception in thread Thread-1:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in
>   _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py",
>   line 688, in addkey_func
>       func(**kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py",
>   line 386, in add_key
>       return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py",
>   line 273, in add_ppa_signing_key
>       cleanup(tmp_keyring_dir)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py",
>   line 234, in cleanup
>       shutil.rmtree(tmp_keyring_dir)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 480, in rmtree
>       _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 438, in _rmtree_safe_fd
>       onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 436, in _rmtree_safe_fd
>       os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Нет такого файла или каталога:
>   'S.gpg-agent.browser'

В гугле нашел, что репозиторий все равно должен добавться, но

> [~] $ sudo apt-get install notepadqq Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
>
> Построение дерева зависимостей        Чтение информации о состоянии…
>
> Готово E: Не удалось найти пакет notepadqq

Что делать?

Comment: ну, вообще-то помойка ppa — это сугубо убунтовское изобретение. проблемы, с которыми вы столкнулись, конечно, решаемы, но само их наличие как бы намекает: вы явно используете не тот дистрибутив.

Answer (score 0):

я notepaddqq ставил через sudo dpkg -i имя пакета.deb предварительно скачав его и полностью поддерживаю, в debian лучше не злоупотреблять ppa

Comment: Хмм.. А я устанавливаю через `sudo apt install имя пакета.deb`. Интересно, в чём разница?

Comment: Основное отличие в том, что apt в состоянии управлять зависимостями, и если надо скачивает и устанавливает их, dpkg нет, зависимости надо ставить вручную.
Есть еще gdebi, он тоже сам справляется с зависимостями